# Input command in linux/windows console with new string

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

I want to input console comand with new string.
f.e.

[image: want as these]

instead

[image: instead these]

Comment: `PS1="userntl@ADRENALIN /c/work/git-projects/\n"; export PS1`? Not really clear what you're wanting here, so I'm guessing that you need to research how to set your primary prompt string `PS1`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell variable PS1 controls the content of the primary prompt, which is the prompt that occurs repeatedly as you give commands to a shell.

Suppose your “userntl@ADRENALIN /c/work/git-projects/” form consists of username, a portion of machine name, and the current directory.  You can arrange that your login shells display a prompt of your desired form by adding either of the lines displayed below near the end of file `~/.bashrc`.  If you modify `.bashrc` you can test it by sourcing it, ie, by entering the command  `. ~/.bashrc` (ie, a dot, a space, a filename), but can also test the commands shown by entering them at a `bash` prompt.

```
export PS1="\\u@\\h \\w\n\\$ "
export PS1='\u@\h \w\n\$ '
```

See the PROMPTING section of `man bash` for an explanation of the `\u, \h, \w` codes.  Note, you might find the following prompt form useful too: `export PS1='\n\h \w > '`

Comment: Thank you, it's work!
And for windows we can use `prompt [text]`
For more detail [Microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true)